# Including a text file in Chrome extension and reading it with Javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I want to create a Chrome extension that contains a text file with static data (a dictionary of English words) and I want the extension to be able to parse that file. I've only managed to find FileReader class, but it looks like it's made for reading user-selected files, while in my case I always want to read the same exact file included in extension's package. As a workaround, I can convert the file to a Javascript array of strings declared in some .js file included in the manifest, but in that case the whole contents would be loaded into memory at once, while what I need is to read the data line by line. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go the `FileReader` route, since you can obtain the Entry of your package directory with [`chrome.runtime.getPackageDirectoryEntry()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getPackageDirectoryEntry).

However, an easier way is to just make a XHR to your file using [`chrome.runtime.getURL()`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/runtime#method-getURL) with a relative path. The first way is useful when you want to list files, though.